# EF 6.0 how to exec parameterless stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

iam using Entity Framework 6.1 and iam wondering what iam supposed to use to execute parameterless procedures. The Method Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() and Database.SqlQuery() both requires parameters. I figgured that I could pass an Empty string but Iam not sure its the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` and `Database.SqlQuery` both take a `params object[] parameters` array, so you don't have to supply anything - it will simply be treated as an empty array if you do `db.ExecuteSqlCommand("foo");` etc.